# How to align a rotating wheel to stop in center position not random position using javascripts?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, wordpress

I am trying to create a wheel on wordpress using javascript. I have done making the wheel and it's spinning randomly after click and stopping now on any random position.

I would like to edit the wheel function, so it will stop on center position of each part of the wheel. Also, I would like the  wheel not to stop and repeat any section again. So in each click for spin wheel will stop in a new section. And stop in center position of wheel. Possible?

Here what I have used to spin the wheel on WordPress

```
<img src="elevatingpolitics.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/EP-wheel.png" alt="" usemap="#linkwheel" width="500" height="auto" style="">


var img = document.querySelector('img');
img.addEventListener('click', onClick, false);


function onClick() {
    this.removeAttribute('style');

    var deg = 1500 + Math.round(Math.random() * 1500);

    var css = '-webkit-transform: rotate(' + deg + 'deg);';

    this.setAttribute(
        'style', css
    );
}
```

[Here is the wheel image with some sections I am using](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IDVti.jpg)!!

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do some simple math like:

```js
var img = document.querySelector('img');
img.addEventListener('click', onClick, false);


function onClick() {
    this.removeAttribute('style');

    var deg =Math.floor(Math.random() * 360);

     //split the degrees in 8 values
     var cad = deg%8;//get the closest value
     deg = cad*45;//set it
    var css = '-webkit-transform: rotate(' + deg + 'deg);';

    this.setAttribute(
        'style', css
    );
}
```

```css
img { transition: transform 1s linear; vertical-align: middle; }
```

```html
<img src="http://elevatingpolitics.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/EP-wheel.png" alt="" usemap="#linkwheel" width="500" height="auto" style="">
```

Note: you may want to put the center in a different picture or remove the text and use a div over the picture

Comment: The property `transform` without vendor prefixes should be added. Adding `img { transition: transform 1s linear; vertical-align: middle; }`  to the CSS illustrates what the JS function is doing. As a suggestion, another element could be created, which rotates as well, on top of that image to make the text selectable, this would improve accessibility... Taking this further, SVG could be used. Something like [**this**](https://sarasoueidan.com/tools/circulus/).

Comment: @Ricky_Ruiz you can always do more but for this answer this will suffice :)

Comment: lol madalin, at least he transition could have been added:-)
I agree, there is much more work to do here, I hav erecreated this with an animation but the image is jumpy I don't even see why, this should be done from scratch with something like Raphael or canvas. BTW what exactly is : var deg = 1500 + Math.round(Math.random() * 1500); doing? I just don't get it o0?

Comment: Ricky that is some good stuff on the link, not sure it's worth to include extra libraries(greensock) for that, but it looks very good. Does that work in all browsers?

Comment: made some adjustments :)

Answer (score 0):

I have modified you code to spin animate it and calculate the degree
Here is working JSFiddle: [spin animate](http://jsfiddle.net/sawan1990/va14rnfk/11/)

```
var img = document.querySelector('img');
img.addEventListener('click', onClick, false);
var arr = [45, 90, 135, 180, 225, 270, 315];
var current_deg = 0;

function getDegree() {
  if (arr.length <= 0) {
    return -1;
  }
  var i = Math.round(Math.random() * 1000) % arr.length;
  var deg = Math.round(Math.random() * 100) * 360 + arr[i];
  arr.splice(i, 1);
  return deg;
}

function onClick() {
  jQuery(img).removeAttr('style');
  var deg = getDegree();
  if (deg >= 0) {
    jQuery({deg: current_deg}).animate({deg: deg}, {
      duration: 2000,
      step: function(now) {
        // in the step-callback (that is fired each step of the animation),
        // you can use the `now` paramter which contains the current
        // animation-position (`0` up to `angle`)
        jQuery(img).css({
          transform: 'rotate(' + now + 'deg)'
        });
      }
    });
    current_deg = deg;
  } else{
        jQuery(img).css({
          transform: 'rotate(0deg)'
      });
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so so so much Sawan Shah. Your solution is exactly what I wanted!! It's not repeating the sections. Just two questions to you. If you are willing to answer them.  1) How can I  slow down the spinning speed? 2) The wheel is stop working after a specific number of clicks. Can I make it random? Again Thank you so much. And thanks a lot madalin ivascu too!!

Answer (score 0):

```js
var img = document.querySelector('img');
img.addEventListener('click', onClick, false);


function onClick() {
    this.removeAttribute('style');

    var deg =Math.floor(Math.random() * 360);

     //split the degrees in 8 values
     var cad = deg%8;//get the closest value
     deg = cad*45;//set it
    var css = '-webkit-transform: rotate(' + deg + 'deg);';

    this.setAttribute(
        'style', css
    );
}
```

```css
img { transition: transform 1s linear; vertical-align: middle; }
```

```html
<img src="http://elevatingpolitics.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/EP-wheel.png" alt="" usemap="#linkwheel" width="500" height="auto" style="">
```

```js
var img = document.querySelector('img');
img.addEventListener('click', onClick, false);


function onClick() {
    this.removeAttribute('style');

    var deg =Math.floor(Math.random() * 360);

     //split the degrees in 8 values
     var cad = deg%8;//get the closest value
     deg = cad*45;//set it
    var css = '-webkit-transform: rotate(' + deg + 'deg);';

    this.setAttribute(
        'style', css
    );
}
```

```css
img { transition: transform 1s linear; vertical-align: middle; }
```

```html
<img src="http://elevatingpolitics.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/EP-wheel.png" alt="" usemap="#linkwheel" width="500" height="auto" style="">
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).